# Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function sortResponses() {
  var Sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Fall 01")
  sheet.sort(3, false);
}
```

I have a Sheet called `Fall 01` in my google Sheets, where I explicítly had to give the script access to, but it won't open, what am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

### Explanation/Issue:

The issue is that you have a [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) script which therefore **is not** bound to a google spreadsheet and as a result `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns `null`.

### Solutions:

There are two ways you can follow:

**Solution 1:**

Use [SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or [SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl):

`var Sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Put your Spreadsheet ID").getSheetByName("Fall 01");`

or

`var Sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Put your Spreadsheet URL").getSheetByName("Fall 01");`

**Solution 2:**

Go to the spreadsheet file that you want to work with and click on `Tools => Script editor` on the top menu of the spreadsheet file and put your current code there.

**Please Note**

If this is your only code, `sheet` is not defined, therefore you will get another error down the road. You most likely want to replace `sheet` with `Sheets` or the other way around. Be careful with this.

Comment: Oh, that worked, thank you and I haven't even seen that I slipped a capital S and another s in the word "sheet", so thanks for the extra note!
Well maybe you can help me with a follow up question to that "code".
So it found the sheet, but now I get nearly the same error, but for the 'sort',
so it tells me, that it "cannot read property 'sort' of null".

Comment: don't forget to add the library: